# AngularJS: Creating Query Form for Database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am having a little problem creating a very simple query form due to my lack of understanding about coding. As you can see in the app.js below, I have FormController, which retrieves information from the form, feeds it into the jsonUrlGen function which creates a custom URL, which is then sent to my SolrController which accesses that URL and pulls the JSON information from it.

However it is quite clear after taking a step back and looking at it that the structure of my code is wrong, and I am missing an app.service to link the shared variables between my two controllers. I'm also not even sure if I need two controllers in this instance, but it just happened as I was coding it.

If anybody can tell me what I'm doing wrong here I would really appreciate it, because the code just flat out does not work.

Thanks.

.HTML FILE

```
<html ng-app="solrApp">
<head>
    <link link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<h1 class="headline">Logo or Something Here</h1>-->
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/CubedE.png" id="cubedE"/></div>
    <div class = "queryForm" ng-controller="FormController">
        <input type="text" class="queryBox" id="mainQueryString" placeholder="Query String" ng-model="fullQuery.queryString"><br />
        <input type="text" class="queryBox" placeholder="Filter Query" ng-model="fullQuery.filterQuery"><br />
        <input type="text" class="queryBox" placeholder="Sort By" ng-model="fullQuery.sortBy"><br />
        <h2>Extract only from rows:</h2>
        <input type="text" class="halfQueryBox" placeholder="Start" ng-model="fullQuery.startRow"><input type="text" class="halfQueryBox" placeholder="End" ng-model="fullQuery.endRow"><br />
        <input type="text" class="queryBox" placeholder="Field List (Separate by comma)" ng-model="fullQuery.fieldList"><br />
        <input type="text" class="queryBox" placeholder="Raw Query Parameters (key1=val1&key2=val2)" ng-model="fullQuery.rawQuery"><br />
        <button type="button" ng-click="jsonUrlGen()">Submit Query</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "results" ng-controller="SolrController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{ item.key }} - <em>{{ item.value }}</em>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

APP.JS

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('solrApp', []);

    app.controller('FormController', function($scope) {

        $scope.fullQuery = {
            queryString: '',
            filterQuery: '',
            sortBy: '',
            startRow: '',
            endRow: '',
            fieldList: '',
            rawQuery: ''
        }

        $scope.jsonUrlGen = function(){

            var jsonURL = "http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?";

            if($scope.fullQuery.queryString !== '') {
                jsonURL =  jsonURL + "q=" + $scope.fullQuery.queryString;  
            }
            else if($scope.fullQuery.filterQuery !== '') {
                jsonURL = jsonURL + "&fq=" + $scope.fullQuery.filterQuery;
            }
            else if($scope.fullQuery.sortBy !== '') {
                jsonURL = jsonURL + "&sort=" + $scope.fullQuery.sortBy;
            }
            else if($scope.fullQuery.startRow !== '') {
                jsonURL = jsonURL + "&start=" + $scope.fullQuery.startRow;
            }
            else if($scope.fullQuery.endRow !== '') {
                jsonURL = jsonURL + "&rows=" + $scope.fullQuery.endRow;
            }
            else if($scope.fullQuery.fieldList !== '') {
                jsonURL = jsonURL + "&fl=" + $scope.fullQuery.fieldList;
            }
            else {
                return "exception thrown";    
            }

            jsonURL = jsonURL + "wt=json";
            return jsonURL;
        };

    });

    app.controller('SolrController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get($scope.jsonUrlGen)
        .then(function(res){
            $scope.items = res.data;
        });

    });

    })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers may be opinionated since there are multiple ways to accomplish this.

I would advise to restructure html. Have a single controller that wraps the "form" and the contents of `SolrController`. Also the "form" should really become a `<form>`. In angular there is a default controller created for this tag and it helps a lot with managing [validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and handling [submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit).

```
<div class="results" ng-controller="SolrController">
  <form class="queryForm" name="queryForm" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" class="queryBox" id="mainQueryString" placeholder="Query String" ng-model="fullQuery.queryString"><br />
    <input type="text" class="queryBox" placeholder="Filter Query" ng-model="fullQuery.filterQuery"><br />
    <input type="text" class="queryBox" placeholder="Sort By" ng-model="fullQuery.sortBy"><br />
    <h2>Extract only from rows:</h2>
    <input type="text" class="halfQueryBox" placeholder="Start" ng-model="fullQuery.startRow"><input type="text" class="halfQueryBox" placeholder="End" ng-model="fullQuery.endRow"><br />
    <input type="text" class="queryBox" placeholder="Field List (Separate by comma)" ng-model="fullQuery.fieldList"><br />
    <input type="text" class="queryBox" placeholder="Raw Query Parameters (key1=val1&key2=val2)" ng-model="fullQuery.rawQuery"><br />
    <button ng-disabled="queryForm.$invalid">Submit Query</button>
  </form>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{ item.key }} - <em>{{ item.value }}</em>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Mind `name` attribute for the form. It will help to access the form in the scope. Actually when there is a name angular creates `$scope.queryForm` in parent controller
By default all buttons (and `<input type="submit"`) on form submit on click. But `type="button"` will prevent it. So remove it

Controller `SolrController`. It's inappropriate to perform a request before user had a change to input something. `$http.get` should work on a click handler which we choose to be submit event.

```
app.controller('SolrController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.fullQuery = {};//ng-model will take care of creating all properties
    function jsonUrlGen(){ //same code here
    }
    $scope.submit = function(){
        $http.get(jsonUrlGen())
            .then(function(res){
                $scope.items = res.data;
            });
        });
    };
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok so I applied all of your code, however for some reason jsonUrlGen is not defined. I was trying it in the console, and not only was nothing being returned but an exception was being thrown. Would you know why the jsonUrlGen function is not working?

Comment: Nevermind I found the answer, that anonymous function tag at the top of my app.js page made the module invisible. Removed it and works fine, thanks!!!!