# AngularJS: single page app with query string and form?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-ui-router

It's common sense that AngularJS is aimed at SPA (single page application) development. Nonetheless, it is also possible to create a MPA (multi page application).

My app is based on multiple states using Angular libraries such as `ui-router` and `ngResource`. First I have an `index.html` file in which I load all the dependencies and a `ui-view`. Then I have three different modules: one main module that contains the top states, a first home page and loads all needed third-party modules. The other module, is named Student and has a simple form to `POST` some data in our Django back-end.

The problem lays in the third module: the company module. Here we have two navigation bars: one top navigation bar, that for now doesn't have any content, and then a sidebar that contains several buttons, such as shown in the image:

[image]

For now, each of those buttons on the sidebar takes the user to a different state, in which a view is loaded in the space where you can see the "Welcome..."

Basically, our states are defined like this:

```
'use strict';

talentforce_company
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'eehNavigationProvider',
     function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, eehNavigationProvider) {



        // Company area states

        $stateProvider.state('companyState', {
              url: '/company',
              abstract: true,
              //redirectTo: 'homeState',
              template: '<company-area-directive></company-area-directive>'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('homeState', {
              url: '/home',
              parent: 'companyState', 
              controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.name_filter = "";
                    $rootScope.city_filter = "";
                }
              ],
              template: '<h3>Welcome to TalentForce company area home</h3>'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('select_study_areas', {
            url: '/select_areas',
            parent: 'companyState',
            template: '<study-areas-directive></study-areas-directive>'
          });

        $stateProvider.state('TalentForceState_seeProfile', {
            url: '/profile_list',
            parent: 'companyState',
            // controller: 'People_Controller',
            template: '<people-directive></people-directive>',
          });

          $stateProvider.state('student', { 
            url: '/profile/{personId}',
            parent: 'companyState',
            //templateUrl: 'public/templates/person_template.html',
            controller: 'Person_Controller',
            template: '<profile-directive></profile-directive>',
            resolve: {
              student: function(student_service, $stateParams) {
                  return student_service.getStudents().find(function(student) { 
                    return (student.student_id == $stateParams.personId);
                  });
                }
              }
          });


        eehNavigationProvider
          .menuItem('TF_menu_top.users', {
            text: 'USERNAME',
            iconClass: 'glyphicon-user',
            href: '#'
          });


        eehNavigationProvider
          .menuItem('TF_sidebar.home', {
            text: 'Home',
            state: 'homeState',
            iconClass: 'fa fa-home fa-fw',
          })
          .menuItem('TF_sidebar.profile', {
            text: 'Company Profile',
            href: '#',
            iconClass: 'fa fa-building fa-fw'
          })
          .menuItem('TF_sidebar.students', {
            text: 'Profiles',
            state: 'select_study_areas',
            //href: '/select_areas',
            iconClass: 'fa fa-users fa-fw'
          })
          .menuItem('TF_sidebar.posts', {
            text: 'Job Posts',
            href: '#',
            iconClass: 'fa fa-list-alt fa-fw'
          })
          .menuItem('TF_sidebar.stats', {
            text: 'Statistics',
            href: '#',
            iconClass:'fa fa-bar-chart fa-fw'
          })
          .menuItem('TF_sidebar.universities', {
            text: 'Universities',
            href: '#',
            iconClass:'fa fa-university fa-fw'
          })
          .menuItem('TF_sidebar.tips', {
            text: 'Tips',
            href: '#',
            iconClass: 'fa fa-check-square-o fa-fw'
          })
          .menuItem('TF_sidebar.events', {
            text: 'Events',
            href: '#',
            iconClass: 'fa fa-calendar fa-fw'
          })
          .menuItem('TF_sidebar.help', {
            text: 'Help',
            href: '#',
            iconClass: 'fa fa-question fa-fw'
          })

    }]);
```

I still don't know if it is relevant, but note that the parent state is abstract, in which the navbars are placed. All the content is then loaded with the navbars always around it. So, if we observe the URL's, they always point to different states and thus different views of the application. So far it seems a great approach.

If we go to the "Profiles" area, I'm using a checkbox for the user to select some areas of interest. And then clicks apply, so as to go to the next state. This state has the same problem that I'm explaining now.

So in this next state, we get to a filtering page. Supposedly, with the previous checkboxes, we would choose three areas, and by clicking "Apply", we would have to send a query to our database in order to only show the results of people that exist in these three areas. Our URL would have something like this, using query strings and forms: `oursite.com/offers/?page=1&s=date&s_l=0&s_h=100&t_co=false&t_st=false&hd=false`

In this filtering page, we would work with that URL, and then apply some more filters. What is happening is that we are doing the filter (currently we have only one) and the URL stays the same, without any query string.

Our filter is wrapped on a form:

```
<form class="filters" id="myFormId" role="form">

            <div class="col-sm-2" id="filter-column">
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="country" name="country">
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="au">Australia</option>
                        <option value="br">Brazil</option>
                        <option value="ca">Canada</option>
                        <option value="fr">France</option>
                        <option value="de">Germany</option>
                        <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
                        <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
                        <option value="it">Italy</option>
                        <option value="za">South Africa</option>
                        <option value="es">Spain</option>
                        <option value="pt" selected>Portugal</option>
                        <option value="us">U.S.A.</option>
                        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-2" id="filter-column">
                <div id="locationField">
                  <input class="search" id="form-input" name="student_city" placeholder="Enter a city" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

The idea is to reload the results (and because of that, reload the page with the query string in the URL) everytime we update a filter.

Notice that we use the `name` attribute so that in our controller, we can do:

```
var queryString = $('#myFormId').serialize();
```

And when we print the `queryString` in the console, it actually constructs it well: `country=pt&student_city=Montijo%2C+Portugal`

But I don't know where and how to use this string. Am I supposed to use a JSON file? How can this dynamic filtering be done in an Angular app? Do I need to change my architecture, or even worse, change framework?

I'm afraid that by using all this states and routes I can't have this type of filters. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I can't find any tutorials on the Internet, the closest I got was [here](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angularjs-query-string-handling-using-locationsearch) because it actually explains a problem similar to mine, but I tried to emulate the solution, and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

If I good understand your problem, then you want to send data from one state to another. There is `$stateParams` service in ui-router which solves this case. You can find docs here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing about it.

So you have state **A** where you choose some filters. To use binding it is easy to gather info from user. So you will have some object like:

```
{
    color: red,
    sort: ascending,
    sortBy: name
}
```

You create an AJAX request via $http where you get data from server like this:

```
$http.get("http(s)://serverurl.com/api/endpoint?color=red&sort=ascending&sortBy=name").then(function(resp){
      //handle response as you want
      //you can go to next state via $state.go("stateB", {params: resp.data}) and render view according to the new data
});
```

In state **B** you will have some controller and you will use `$stateParams` to get new data what you have requested on state **A**.

I provide an another example I think it demonstrates how it can work:

Definition of states:

```
{ 
  name: 'people', 
  url: '/people',
  resolve: {
    people: function(PeopleService) {
      return PeopleService.getAllPeople();
    }
  }
},

{ 
  name: 'people.person', 
  url: '?isActive&eyeColor',
  resolve: {
    filteredPeople: function(people, $stateParams) {
      var res = [];
      people.find(function(person) { 
        if(shouldWeAddToFiltered($stateParams))
        {
          res.push(person);
        }

      });
      return res;
    }
  },
  controller: function(filteredPeople){
      //do something with filteredPeople array
  }
}
```

In this case your url is updated. So users can bookmark the page.

Comment: The thing is, in the filtering case, I do not want to pass data between states, it is really a query to my server, using the query string. And then load the page with the information received.

Comment: So you have some checkboxes where user can choose some of them and then you create a reguest POST or something to server with those choosen data?

Comment: Exactly. That will filter the data and return a list of people on a new page (or state?). Then, there I have other filter such as city, skills, etc. I want to create a query string that shows on the URL, in order to query the DB directly and then reload the page with the new data.

Comment: I have updated the answer. It is some kind of pseudo code. I just want to present the idea how I try to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm already doing that. But those changes do not propagate to the URL of the Angular app. The problem, using a sentence from the tutorial I linked in my question, is: "But what if you want some way to record the state of the page? Say your users want to bookmark a set of filters, or email a link to their coworkers?"

You see? As it is, there is no way for the filters to be specified/serialized in the URL

Comment: I have found you something https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters It seems that is it possible to add query params to url.

Comment: I saw that, but that doesn't add them dynamically. I always have to code the states and params.
I wanted something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706110/angularjs-creating-query-form-for-database

Comment: I tried it by myself with query params described in docs is working well. URL is updated in all cases so I think this is a way to solve this issue. Here you just needs to know all filter parameters and after that everything else is solved by ui-router. Updates the url, you can access to params via $stateParams, users can bookmark the url because every info is there. So I think it is a right way to do that. I do not see what do you mean under "oesn't add them dynamically"? You have to take care about state object **ones** when you define it.

Comment: could you link a plunker as a working example? I can show you some of my code if you want